# How to detect which program is leaking memory

Tags: ubuntu, memory, memory-leaks

I am using ubuntu 15.04 and my idle memory usage is usually around 1GB, recently I've been getting `memory allocation failed` from node.

I noticed after a day or two my idle memory goes up to 4GB. I know it's either a program or ubuntu. I'm really hoping it's not ubunut so I don't have to reinstall it or downgrade.

What's the best tool to determine which program is leaking memory or is it ubuntu itself.

Comment: Use `top` or `htop`as explained here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1389253  This lists all processes and shows which process is using how many memory space.

Comment: Ubuntu isn't a thing, it is a collection of things.  Run the command `top` then hit M (shift-m) to order by memory usage.

Comment: That was my first instinct, the highest usage is Xorg with like 2% but 50% of my memory is gone.

Comment: please post the output of `free`, when you are experiencing problems.

Answer (score 1):

You could do these in two ways

1)Run the `top command (to run non-interactively, type top -b -n 1)`. To see applications which are leaking memory, look at the following columns:

> ```
> RPRVT - resident private address space size
> RSHRD - resident shared address space size
> RSIZE - resident memory size
> VPRVT - private address space size
> VSIZE - total memory size
> ```

2)Grab a debugger/memory profiler like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and run the programs one after one in it.

Comment: The columns use mention aren't in fields management menu (press `f`)